# Sharing mac WiFi over Ethernet breaks all internet connections

Tags: mac, airport, internet-sharing, router

I'm trying to share internet from my macbook to my iMac. The macbook connects via WiFi, and I want to share it's internet over ethernet to the iMac.

WHen I set this up in sharing and turn on internet sharing, my macbook loses all internet connectivity. I can only get it back by turning off sharing and then disconnecting and reconnecting to my WiFi. My settings are below:
[image]

The iMac doesn't get any connectivity either. It recognises that there is an ethernet connection and it get's an IP, but it can't access the internet.

Comment: Across about 5 Macs and 4 versions of the OS (Snow Leopard to Mavericks) I have *never* been able to get sharing of my wifi connection over ethernet.

Answer (score 2):

The order of your internet connections is reversed.

For internet connection sharing to work it should be:

"Share your connection from Ethernet"

"To computers using Wi-Fi".

Here are the instructions:
http://mac.appstorm.net/how-to/internet-howto/sharing-your-internet-connection-via-wi-fi/

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.